# Always times out at 10 seconds regardless of setting

Tags: webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I am running a simple WebDriverIO script, and inserting any amount of async behaviour is making it time out at the 10 sec threshold (or before?). I want to control the timeout setting, but no matter what I try I cannot increase it.

As I am using ChromeDriver, not all Selenium settings are applicable, and setting `browser.timeouts('implicit', 30000)` (or `script` or `pageLoad`) will throw an error: `unknown error: unknown type of timeout:pageLoad`.

The [only other timeouts I have found](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/timeouts.html) are

- mochaOpts.timeout
- waitforTimeout

This is my test:

```
it.only('should be able to register', ()=>{
  // Mocha timeout
  this.timeout(50000)

  browser.url('/encounter/new');

  browser.waitUntil( function() {
    return browser.isExisting('[name=lastName]');
  });

  browser.setValue('#problem', 'something fishy'); 

  // this is problematic: comment this out and everything works
  // also works with very small timeouts
  browser.executeAsync(function(done){
    setTimeout(done, 1000);
  });

  browser.click('#appdetailsheader button');
  console.log(browser.getUrl(), browser.log('browser'))

  browser.waitUntil( function() {
    return !browser.isExisting('[name=lastName]');
  });

  console.log(browser.getTitle(), browser.getUrl());
  console.log(browser.log('browser'))
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can totally understand you frustration. WebdriverIO is extremely modular & configurable, but this comes with an increased level of complexity which often leads to confusion.

---

**For this:**

```
 // Mocha timeout
 this.timeout(50000);
```

**!!!** This has no effect because you are configuring/setting your Mocha timeout in an **[arrow function](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/)** which is discouraged by Mocha. Read more about it **[here](https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions)**.

**Solution** (pick as applicable to your setup):

- run your script with **[WebdriverIO test-runner](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/gettingstarted.html)** and set `mochaOpts: { timeout: <desiredTimeout>}`, or you can even override it from your test run: `wdio wdio.config.js --mochaOpts.timeout=<desiredTimeout>`;
- set your `timeout` in your root `describe` statement, or even better, in a `before` hook: `before(function() { this.timeout(<desiredTimeout>); (...)});`;
- if you're running your test case using Mocha, pass the timeout either into your CLI command (if you're using it to run your tests): `mocha yourTestFile.js --timeout <desiredTimeout>`, or change it's value in your `mocha.opts` file;

**Note:** I'm sure there are even more ways to do this, but these are a few that worked for me.

---

**For this:**

```
  browser.waitUntil( function() {
      return browser.isExisting('[name=lastName]');
  });
```

**!!!** This will always wait for the existence of the `element` with attribute `name="lastName"` for the default `1000 ms` before timing out. This value can be changed via `waitforTimeout`.

**Solution** (pick as applicable to your setup):

- explicitly give your `waitUntil...`/`waitfor...` commands the timeout: `browser.waitUntil( function() { return browser.isExisting('[name=lastName]');}, <desiredTimeout>, <errorMessage>);`;
- run your script with **[WebdriverIO test-runner](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/gettingstarted.html)** and set `waitforTimeout: <desiredTimeout>`, or you can even override it from your test run: `wdio wdio.config.js --waitforTimeout=<desiredTimeout>`;

---

Finally, I tried to run a few test cases with obscene timeout values (`50000 ms`) and it worked as expected for every one of the issues you mentioned above.

**waitforTimeout example**:

**Logs** (`1 failing (57s)`):

```
[chrome #0-0]         ConnectWeb Devices Content Test Suite
[chrome #0-0]           1) "before all" hook
[chrome #0-0]
[chrome #0-0]
[chrome #0-0] 1 failing (57s)
[chrome #0-0]
[chrome #0-0] 1) ConnectWeb Devices Content Test Suite "before all" hook:
[chrome #0-0] Oups! An error occured.
Timed out waiting for element ('span[connectqa-device="events"]') to exist
```

---

**Note:** I've never used Selenium timeouts in WebdriverIO before (`implicit`, `pageLoad`, `script`), but I never had this necessity before as `waitforTimeout` & Mocha's `timeout` have been more than effective for my testing scenarios.

**Small mention:** This statement `inserting any amount of async behaviour is making it time out at the 10 sec threshold` is not true. First off, WDIO is completely asynchronous. You might be using the `sync: true` flag, but behind the scenes, everything is still async.

This is a vast topic and I tried to cover as much as possible given the information at hand. Sorry if I didn't completely answer your question. Tell me in the comments and I'll try to update the answer with the relevant info.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: thank you for a thorough and detailed answer! It's kind of ironic that I fell victim to the arrow function vs `this` problem, as this is usually something I need to tell people that use the `sinon-test` lib. The reason it didn't hit me was that the outer context of the describe block also has a `timeout` method, so calling `this.timeout()` didn't result in a runtime error which would have alerted me earlier. I now see that calling `this.timeout` in the describe block sets a "block scope" timeout for the tests that _are to be_ run.

Comment: btw, what I meant with "async behaviour" was the `executeAsync` part of the script. I just meant that adding a few millis of runtime execution through `setTimeout` would hit the threshold. I know about the tricks WDIO uses to hide the async nature of the underlying promise-based API, so it wasn't that :-)

Comment: @oligofren you're welcome, wanted to reply sooner, but the answer needed more tinkering so I postponed the reply.  `I now see that calling this.timeout in the describe block sets a "block scope" timeout for the tests that are to be run` <= YES, precisely. Yeah, regarding the async, just pointed out the inconsistency didn't want to have shots fired. :) Anyways, you're question also got me thinking about the Selenium timeouts, which I never used so I'll probably go ahead and see what scenarios they'd actually be better suited for. Cheers man!